# How to stop PDF scrolling back to the top with every compile?

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I am using Texmaker alongside MiKTeX. I have created a very simple LaTeX Document, and every time I run 'quick build', the PDF scrolls back to the top of the document. In the tutorial I'm watching, every time she presses it the document stays in the same place, which is obviously far more convenient.

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but I ask for clarification: Is the PDF continuously open, or do you close and re-open between compile?

Comment: It is continuously open. E.g. I compile it, edit some code, recompile, and it scrolls back to the top